# Can't choose the time for an appointment on visa4uk

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I am trying to apply for a visa and the [website](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome) doesn't let me pick the time for an appointment, although I can see the menu to pick the time just for a second, after then it disappears and shows me that there is no time available for an appointment whatsoever.

I called the support and they are suggesting to use very old versions of Internet Explorer although Windows doesn't even allow me to download such an old version of the browser.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to go and tell support that you can't do what they are asking and ask them for more help. While you might get some help here the support for that website are more likely to be in a position to help (eg they might be able to submit the information for you if there are actually appointments available). Another option is that the message may be correct and it might be an asynchronous request that checks this which is why you saw the menu briefly.

Comment: Try another browser. It's not so hard to install, then deinstall, one.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you choose a different location?

Comment: What is the location you selected?